# svg and png output in html to pdf download

Tags: javascript, html, svg, pdf-generation

I created a html page. this page displayed circle with svg path and also a png file included in this page. now i want to download this page as pdf file. so please help me.
I used javascript codes but not satisfied.

```
<html>     <script src="http://parall.ax/parallax/js/jspdf.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
**<img src="bodysmall.png" id="m">**
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // draw cloud
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(170, 80);
  context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
  context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
  context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
  context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
      context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
  context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);
  context.closePath();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
  context.fill();
  context.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';
  context.stroke();

  // only jpeg is supported by jsPDF
  var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
  var pdf = new jsPDF();
  pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
  pdf.save("download.pdf");
    </script>
```

Comment: _"I used javascript codes but not satisfied."_ ? Can describe issue ? Expected results not returned ?

Comment: I want the pdf output from simple html page contained svg shapes and png file

Comment: Current `js` does not achieve expected result ? What is result of `pdf.save("download.pdf");` ?

Comment: Tried using `print()` ?

Comment: this code saves only svg shapes not png file

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/by3LsLuu/6/

Comment: i already tried this code but i want to download pdf file with on click event

Comment: Try saving document as `.pdf` , using `a` element with `href` to to saved `.pdf` file

Comment: **1**, you are not using svg but canvas. **2** to download the image from `bodysmall.png`, you'll have to make sure no crossorigin issue happens, and then you'll have to draw this image into an other canvas, and call the `addImage(scdCanvas.toDataURL(), ...)` method.